# Axes_Grid1: Ticks, tick-labels and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm invoking my grid as

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid
grid  = AxesGrid(fig, 111,
                            nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                            axes_pad=0.05,
                            share_all=True,
                            label_mode="L",
                            cbar_location="right",
                            cbar_mode="single",
                            )
```

but I seem not to be able to do usual `xticks()`, or `set_xlabel()` commands. I tried through calling `grids[i].imshow()`, and adding them as args to the `AxesGrid()`. The latter was just a leap of faith, it's not really documented. However, nothing like this is done in the tutorials, so I'm really stuck on how to do it.

Comment: Something like `grid.axes_all[0].set_xticks([0,1])` works, but surprisingly (?) that changes the ticks of all subplots.

Comment: Ah, that happens when you set `share_all=True`, when you disable that option you can set e.g. the ticks with the example that I added below

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with `share_all=True`, all axes are updated when changing a single one. If you disable `share_all`, something like this works:

```
import pylab as pl
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

fig = pl.figure()

grid  = AxesGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                 axes_pad=0.05,
                 share_all=False,
                 label_mode="L",
                 cbar_location="right",
                 cbar_mode="single",
                )

ax = grid.axes_all[0]
ax.set_xticks([0,1])
```